# Unable to render svg in Material UI

Tags: css, material-ui, create-react-app

I'm using Material-UI with `create-react-app` and am having trouble rendering an `.svg` file in a drawer header. I get a broken image rendering instead of the `.svg` I'm expecting. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<DrawerHeader>
  <div>
      <Icon classes={{root: classes.iconRoot}}>
          <img className={classes.imageIcon} src="/assets/logo.svg"/>
      </Icon>

  </div>
</DrawerHeader>
```

```
 imageIcon: {
    display: 'flex',
    height: '100%',
    width: 'inherit'
 },
 iconRoot: {
     textAlign: 'center'
 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the image like

```
import Img from '../../logo.svg'
```

then pass it to the src

```
 <img className={classes.imageIcon} src={Img} />
```